# How does run option in geany text editor work?

Tags: text-editor, geany

I have seen the run option (F5) in the Geany text editor. If I run an HTML file it opens a browser and in case of php code it will show all the html content on the terminal. I was wondering what exactly is this run option supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geany documentation explains how this operations work and how to customize them.

http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#build-menu

Answer (score -2):

Just wondering ? So far as I know, it is normal for someone who is writing a computer program, he want to run it.

Geany is very good. We can write a scrip, e.g. python, then run it. And it will run just like a normal IDE like Netbean do. It even will show the result in GUI when we run python with wxPython. Of cource, Python and wxPython must be installed first.

It also able to show output of PHP and/or HTML scrips directely in a Browser, so far as I know, Firefox. Of cource, a Geany project should be set first to do that. Again, web browser, PHP anda MySql must be ready first.

To directly output a PHP scrip in a Browser, e.g. Firefox. Do as follows :

Open a Geany project, then : Project -> Propesties -> Build. There are 3 group option to edit : PHP Command, Independent Command and Execute Command. Thera are 2 columns in Execute Command group.

[Look at the bottom of the window (Click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyyTJ.png)

Fill the second column with :

```
firefox "http://localhost/your_project_folder/%f"
```

And the third column, fill with your document root of your project e.g., `/var/www/html/your_project_folder`.